# Revoking permissions from user on specific tables?

Tags: mysql

I have granted all permissions on a database to a user 'demo' with this command:

```
grant all privileges on wordpress.* to demo@localhost;
```

Now i want to revoke the user permissions on the table wp_users. I used this command:

```
revoke all privileges on wordpress.wp_users from demo@localhost;
```

But i get this error:

```
ERROR 1147 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'demo' on host 'localhost' on table 'wp_users'
```

Why i am getting this error?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57377/revoking-mysql-table-level-privileges

Comment: try `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after `grant all` then `revoke all`

Comment: @sand No, that won't work. See my answer and the stuff PM 77-1 linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Because, as indicated, you're trying to revoke a grant that doesn't exist.

Making a broad grant makes a broad grant; it doesn't automatically make lots of individual grants that you can then cherry-pick away afterwards.

Simply grant access to the tables you want.

Comment: That doesn't look very practical. If i have 100 tables and i want to revoke the permissions just from one table i have to grant the permission to 99 tables one by one.

Comment: @user1800997: Better than forgetting to "revoke" one.

Comment: any way to automate granting permissions to multiple tables?

Comment: @user1800997: Yes; click on the link PM 77-1 gave you an hour ago

Comment: that looks too complicated for a noob like me. any other simpler way?

Comment: @user1800997: A GUI, such as SQLYog.

Comment: thanks, but i am looking for a free solution. can i do this with phpmyadmin? the database is on ubuntu server.

Comment: Download the (slightly older) SQLYog community edition, which is free. Ultimately it is up to you to find a tool that works for you. You have near-infinite options.